# Next.js context provider wrapping App component with page specific layout component giving undefined data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have an auth context component where I'm wrapping my main app component, but at the same time I'm also trying to do page specific layout component per Next.js documentation here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts

Am I doing this correctly, because I can't seem to be getting the data from my Context provider.

**/context/AuthContext.js**

```
const UserContext = createContext({});

export default function AuthContext({children}) {
  // .. code
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

**/_app.js**

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {    

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);

  return getLayout(
    <div>
      <AuthContext>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AuthContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

**/components/Project/List.js**

```
import { useUser } from "../../context/AuthContext";

const ProjectList = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  console.log("get user data", user);

  return (
    <>
      test
    </>
  );
};

export default ProjectList;
```

I'm trying to console log the user, but it's giving me undefined. I'm thinking it's because the way it's wrapped as a layout component? I could be doing this wrong. But I did console log inside my `AuthContext` for user, and the information there is correct.

**/pages/projects/index.js**

```
const Projects = () => {
  // code goes here
  return (
    <div>
      code goes here
    </div> 
  )
}

export default Projects;

Projects.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <ProjectLayout>{page}</ProjectLayout>;
};
```

When I remove the `Projects.getLayout` block of code, the data comes back, but when I add this code, data is gone.

**/components/Project/Layout.js**

```
const ProjectLayout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ProjectList />
      {children}
    </>
  }

export default ProjectLayout
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With your current structure `ProjectLayout` isn't getting wrapped by the `AuthContext`, meaning you won't have access to its context.

You can modify your `_app`'s structure and move the `getLayout` call around so that the context wraps it properly.

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {    
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);

    return (
        <AuthContext>
            {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
        </AuthContext>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem but with <SWRConfig value={{fetcher: ....}} /> in 'next/swr'. I tried your method but the Layout component still doesn't receive the fetcher. Here are some useful link:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#data-fetching and
https://swr.vercel.app/docs/global-configuration
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is the `SWRConfig` properly wrapping the layout component? Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your code. You may want to post your issue as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69681236/next-jss-per-page-layout-component-doesnt-get-value-from-vercels-swr-global-c

Comment: Brilliant, I was having a similar problem while adding Chakra UI's ChakraProvider and ColorModeProvider, and Next Auth's NextAuthProvider to the _app.tsx file.  All is working just fine now with this approach.  Big thanks @juliomalves!

Comment: You star @juliomalves, this has been bugging me for months - I didn't realise you could do it like that with the getLayout being wrapped

Comment: guess it even saves kb in a build using it this way !?

Comment: @juliomalves a big big like and a ton of applause

Answer (score 3):

Note that calling `getLayout` inside the Context could lead to errors **if the `getLayout` function uses hooks or stuff that depends on a parent element**.

It will be calling `getLayout` first and then the context, so the value of it will be initially the default (fallback) value (it's like doing `foo(bar())` and expecting that `foo` will be called before `bar`).

To avoid this, **return directly the component** (using `getLayout` as a function that generates a component):

```
// /pages/projects/index.js
Projects.getLayout = (children) => (
  // can't use hooks here, return the component immediately
  <ProjectLayout>{children}</ProjectLayout>;
);
```

or use the layout as a component:

```js
// /pages/projects/index.js
Projects.Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return <ProjectLayout>{children}</ProjectLayout>;
};

// /pages/_app.js
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {    
  const Layout = Component.Layout || (({ children }) => children);
  return (
     <AuthContext>
       <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
       </Layout>
     </AuthContext>
  );
}
```

---

Edit: The difference is more visible without JSX

```
// incorrect
return React.createElement(AuthContext, null,
  // getLayout is called before AuthContext
  getLayout(
    React.createElement(Component, pageProps)
  )
)

// correct
return React.createElement(AuthContext, null,
  // Layout is called after AuthContext
  React.createElement(Layout, null,
    React.createElement(Component, pageProps)
  )
)
```