# Next.js's per page layout component doesn't get value from Vercel's swr global configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, react-context, swr

The `useSWR` hook from swr works everywhere if I explicitly enter the fetcher.

```
const { data } = useSWR("http://...", fetcher);
```

However, if I used swr global configuration as shown below, the `useSWR` only works in `First` page but not in `HeaderLayout` component. I did some debugging and found out that in `HeaderLayout` doesn't receive the value from swr global configuration (`SWRConfig` in `_app.tsx`) even though it is wrapped inside.

I followed this doc https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts for the page layout implementation

```
// _app.tsx
type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement) => React.ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

  return (
    <SWRConfig
      value={{
        fetcher: (resource, init) =>
          fetch(resource, init).then((res) => res.json()),
      }}
    >
      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </SWRConfig>
  );
}
```

```
// pages/first
const First = () => {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  const { data } = useSWR("http://...");

  return (
    <div>...Content...</div>
  );
};

First.getLayout = HeaderLayout;
```

```
// layout/HeaderLayout
const HeaderLayout = (page: React.ReactElement) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { project: projectId, application: applicationId } = router.query;

  const { data } = useSWR(`http://...`);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {page}
    </>
  );
};
```

Helpful links:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts

https://swr.vercel.app/docs/global-configuration

[Next.js context provider wrapping App component with page specific layout component giving undefined data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078144/next-js-context-provider-wrapping-app-component-with-page-specific-layout-compon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `First.getLayout` property should be a function that accepts a `page` and returns that page wrapped by the `HeaderLayout` component.

```js
First.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
    return (
        <HeaderLayout>{page}</HeaderLayout>
    )
}
```

The `HeaderLayout` is a React component, its first argument contains the `props` passed to it. You need to modify its signature slightly to match this.

```js
const HeaderLayout = ({ children }) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { project: projectId, application: applicationId } = router.query;

    const { data } = useSWR(`http://...`);

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            {children}
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Layouts doesnt work if you declare Page as const. So instead of `const First = () => {...}` do `function First() {...}`