# How can I consume a Redux provider in a layout component rendered via getLayout in a Next.js 'custom app' function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

In `pages/_app`, of my Next.js app, I can wrap my layout in a Redux provider like this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

And then consume the redux provider with `useSelector()` in my layout.

However, if I use `Component.getLayout`, like this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is, and how I can get around it? I want to use the getLayout method because my layout varies from page to page.

Comment: Can you show us how you are defining `getLayout` in your page component?

Comment: Component.getLayout = Layout

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js's per page layout component doesn't get value from Vercel's swr global configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69681358/1870780)? `getLayout` has to be a function.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes it does. Thank you. That's awesome.