# React Query - Client Provider in the _app.tsx using layouts

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I use layouts in my nextjs application, e.g. my homepage includes:

```
Homepage.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <LayoutRoot auth={true}>
      <LayoutDefault>{page}</LayoutDefault>
    </LayoutRoot>
  );
};
```

Now, I'm trying to move `queryClient` into `_app.tsx` following this tutorial:
https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-hydration to prefetch some queries SSR.

Previously I have defined `queryClient` inside `LayoutDefault`, but in the RQ docs I've noticed:

> Create a new QueryClient instance inside of your app, and on an
> instance ref (or in React state). This ensures that data is not shared
> between different users and requests, while still only creating the
> QueryClient once per component lifecycle.

After moving client instance into an app, the error shows:

```
Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
```

My `_app.tsx`:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient());
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
  const Layout = Component.layout ?? Fragment

  return getLayout(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} contextSharing={true}>
        <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
          <div className="page-wrapper">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </div>
        </Hydrate>
      </QueryClientProvider>
 )
```

In the `LayoutRoot` and `LayoutDefault` I have a few contexts that use some queries/mutations.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js context provider wrapping App component with page specific layout component giving undefined data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079558/1870780)? The `QueryClientProvider` isn't wrapping your layout components, meaning you can't access the query client inside them. You need to move the `getLayout()` call so that it gets nested inside `QueryClientProvider`.

Comment: Thanks! It solves my all problems :)