# useContext is not working with layout and nested components Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm trying to call a logout, a nested component within the app that attempts to access the useContext and allow the user to log out.

Logout Component

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {
  CheckerContext,
  useCheckerContext,
} from "../../../context/CheckerContext";
const LogoutBtn = () => {
  const { logout, isAuthenticated } = useCheckerContext();

  const logOutAct = async () => {
    await logout();
    console.log("logged out");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => logOutAct()}>Out</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default LogoutBtn;
```

_app.js

```
    import "../styles/globals.css";
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";
import { AmazonProvider } from "../context/CheckerContext";
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page);
  const APPID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID;
  const SERVERURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL;
  return getLayout(
    <MoralisProvider appId={APPID} serverUrl={SERVERURL}>
      <AmazonProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </AmazonProvider>
    </MoralisProvider>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import HomeGuest from "../components/Checkers/Guests/HomeGuest";

import { NextSeo } from "next-seo";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { useCheckerContext } from "../context/CheckerContext";

export default function Index({ children }) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      animate={{
        fontSize: 50,

        opacity: 1,
      }}
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
    >
      <HomeGuest />
    </motion.div>
  );
}

Index.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
};
```

Context page:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMoralis, useMoralisQuery } from "react-moralis";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export const CheckerContext = createContext();

export const AmazonProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const {
    authenticate,
    isAuthenticated,
    enableWeb3,
    Moralis,
    user,
    isWeb3Enabled,
    logout,
    isAuthenticating,
  } = useMoralis();

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");

  return (
    <CheckerContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        logout,
        isAuthenticating,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CheckerContext.Provider>
  );
};
export function useCheckerContext() {
  return useContext(CheckerContext);
}
```

It returns: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logout')

How can I make use of the context in different components and using different layouts?

Comment: One line of code is breaking the whole thing:     const { logout } = useCheckerContext(); in the logout.js

Comment: Is the `LogoutBtn` used inside the `Layout` component by any chance? If so, does this answer your question: [Next.js context provider wrapping App component with page specific layout component giving undefined data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078144/next-js-context-provider-wrapping-app-component-with-page-specific-layout-compon)?