# Why is the MUI Theme breaking with NextJS Layout

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have my app set up to use a specified layout for each page as per the example on [Nextjs docs for per page layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts).

Layout works fine but the MUI theme breaks

_App.js before layout integration (theme works)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../utils/theme'

export default function MyApp(props) {

  return (

  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ThemeProvider>

  );
}
```

_App.js after layout integration (theme breaks)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../utils/theme'

export default function MyApp(props) {

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)

  return getLayout (

  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ThemeProvider>

  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js context provider wrapping App component with page specific layout component giving undefined data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078144/next-js-context-provider-wrapping-app-component-with-page-specific-layout-compon)? The `ThemeProvider` isn't wrapping your layout components, try moving the `getLayout()` call so that it gets nested inside `ThemeProvider`, i.e. `{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}`.

Answer (score 2):

1. according to [MUI server side rendering document](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/server-rendering/), the code is missing `emotion` 's `<CacheProvider />`, which syncs render result.

```js
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from '@emotion/react';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
  Component: AppProps['Component'] & {layout?: React.Node};
}

export default function App({Component, emotionCache, pageProps}: MyAppProps) {
  return <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </CacheProvider>
}
```

2. the code is expected to replace the whole `<ThemeProvider>` wrapper with your Page layout. With a layout is given, the expected output of `getLayout()` is your layout, without `<ThemeProvider />`. working example of a page with layout should be like this:

```
import { CacheProvider, EmotionCache } from '@emotion/react';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import RootLayout from /* ... your own default layout ... */
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

interface MyAppProps extends AppProps {
  emotionCache?: EmotionCache;
  Component: AppProps['Component'] & {layout?: React.Node};
}

export default function App({Component, emotionCache, pageProps}: MyAppProps) {

  const PageLayout = Component.layout ?? RootLayout;
  // this code does not replace the whole outcome.
  // instead, it just replaces PageLayout component.
  return <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <PageLayout> {/** <-- */}
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PageLayout> {/** <-- */}
    </ThemeProvider>
  </CacheProvider>
}

// usage example
// pages/my-page.tsx
import SomeLayout from /** your custom layout */
export default function MyPage: NextPage & { layout?: React.Node } = () => {
  return <div></div>
}

MyPage.layout = SomeLayout;
```